# In what sense is Marie a vampire?

Tags: chosen

In *Chosen*, Marie tells Emma that she is 99% vampire, but has not drunk blood (yet). This does not have the appearance of a one-off joke: all her friends seem to treat it completely seriously even when Emma says that she is not a vampire at all if she does not drink, she reacts poorly when Emma asks her if she has "tried not being a vampire," and all the children at school appear to know her as a vampire, even bullying her by dropping red drinks in her school bag.

However, though the series is science fictional, she does not seem to be a supernatural vampire, nor do there appear to be supernatural vampires of any sort in the series (human-appearing aliens seem to be more the focus). She does not have any magical powers, does not appear to be undead, and so forth.

- Is she a vampire in the sense of real-world vampires, who tend to be people who identify as "energy vampires" who drain vitality from others? This never seems to be mentioned in the show.
- Is it simply an extended joke, even though she really does not seem to treat it that way?
- Is she actually, somehow, a supernatural vampire?
- Is it a convoluted metaphor for her coming out about her sexuality? This could make some sense with the interactions in her friend circle, with Emma asking her if she had told her father that she was a vampire, and with her reaction to the question of whether she had tried not being a vampire. However, this would not explain why she seems to be generally known as a vampire at school.

In short, in what sense is Marie a vampire?

Answer (score -2):

Marie is **otherkin**! Otherkin: individuals who believe they are in some sort of way (wether spiritual, psychological, etc) non-human (vampires, elves, etc. -- even earthen animals, which are known as 'therians').
I myself am otherkin and a therian.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you provide some evidence that this is a concept embraced by the series, or is it just your own headcanon?  Please only provide answers based on the work itself and official sources for it.

Comment: fair enough. no I don't but its just a headcanon then I guess? its also not the main focus of the series so I don't think they would elaborate on it